# Why do some transactions get confirmed within 5-10 minutes and some don't even after 10 hours?

Tags: transaction, confirmation

I was moving funds between my wallet some tx got confirmed within few minutes and some not even after 10 hours in the same node. I switched nodes and reattached several time and eventually it got confirmed.

My question is:
If i leave that tx in pending state will it eventually get confirmed after hours/days ?

For other coin's I used so far like BTC, ETH, ADA, NEO, etc., if u send funds to some address it will eventually reach that address without further user action. I am not seeing this in IOTA, isn't this a big issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is:
>   If i leave that tx in pending state will it eventually get confirmed after hours/days ?

Unless you `replayBundle` or `promoteTransaction`, your tx will never get confirmed after a certain time because your transaction will be orphaned in the tangle and no other txs will reference it.

The reasons for difference in confirmation time vary.

If the bundle contains too many txs, it would take more time to do PoW and thus by the time you finish the PoW and attach the bundle to the tangle, the location of the attaching is a little behind the latest milestone.

If the node you send your tx to is a little lagging behind the latest milestone, it is also hard to get it confirmed.

However, these conditions are based on the coordinator's operations (eg.milestone). once we get rid of the coordinator, the confirmation consensus is a whole different story.

Comment: Promoting is usually the better solution which you should use if you can. This creates a new transaction referencing yours. As the PoW is faster, this transaction is very likely to be selected